# Visual Studio 2010 addin for enable/disable Code Analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-analysis

When I compile my code with code analysis enabled, it take a long time. Now I need to go to project's property and set it manually. I want to know are there any addin that I can enable/disable code analysis before compile projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is possible, but it's probably not the optimal approach.  Instead, you might want to consider creating a separate build configuration for your solution in which code analysis is disabled (e.g.: "Debug (No FxCop)").  Aside from avoiding reloads of changed project files, this also has the major advantage of preventing accidental check-ins of projects that have code analysis disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand, what exactly you want?
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z0aeatx.aspx):

> To run code analysis each time that you build a project, you select Enable Code Analysis on Build (defines `CODE_ANALYSIS` constant) on the project's Property Page. For more information, see [How to: Enable and Disable Automatic Code Analysis for Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175.aspx).
>
> To run code analysis manually on a project, on the Analyze menu, click Run Code Analysis on ProjectName. For more information, see [How to: Enable and Disable Automatic Code Analysis for Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175.aspx).
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, and then click Properties.
> 2. In the properties dialog box for the project, click Code Analysis.
> 3. Specify the build type in Configuration and the target platform in Platform.
> 4. To enable or disable automatic code analysis, select or clear the Enable Code Analysis on Build (defines `CODE_ANALYSIS` constant) check box.

So it makes no sence to have an Add-in for general property edit action. If you want, you can edit Code Analysis properties for the whole solution in its property configuration: `Solution -> Properties -> Common Properties -> Code Analysis settings`.

See also:

[Visual Studio 2010 Code Analysis - Run on Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824231/visual-studio-2010-code-analysis-run-on-solution)

Comment: I know how to enable/disable code analysis as you suggest but I have about 50 projects and enable/disable them manually take times. I want to know how to create addin or macro to doing this by click one button. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for someone. I am using this utiltiy: https://github.com/jkells/fxcop-nop

It's just tiny executable that enables or disables code analysis my replacing the FXCopCmd.exe with an executable that just returns 0;

It's hard coded with the path to FXCopCmd.exe for VS2012.